Replace old metal risen sprinkler for drip line?
We have these old looking metal sprinklerheads (maybe 2 or 3 feet tall).  They're likely from the '70s, and I'd like to simply add a drip line to these.  There's no brand/model anywhere, and I frankly am new to this and am not even sure what to call them.
Is that possible with some attachment/screw-in thing? Or do I need to replace the entire metal sprinkler?
The pictures show the sprinklerhead up close, and then with the spray-direction bit taken off.  I was hoping there's a simple screw-in thing available I can just screw in and hook drip line hoses to.




Possibly a silly question but...do they work?  Is there a valve that controls the water supply that you can access?  What kind of water pressure comes out?  Regular tap water pressure or has it been downsized?

@kevinskio - yes they still work and is say pressure is... Regular? The spray reaches say ten feet away when running.

@kevinskio - Any ideas? I have been searching the web with my best Google-fu, but can't for the life of me find out what these are even called.  I think this weekend I may just dig down and see what connectors they use, hopefully (big time fingers crossed) I can just replace this metal one with the more common Rainbird/whatever brand pop-up sprinkler/drip line.  However, something about it (age and how I can't even find info on them) makes me think these are totally different.

I don't recognize them and believe this is due to their age.  If I am correct the top piece is soldered on and using copper and solder for outdoor water has not been a popular choice for many years.

If I understand correctly what I'm looking at, it should be possible but moderately annoying to convert these to drip source.
Lacking a scale, it eyeballs as probably 1/2" (nominal) copper pipe with a smaller (1/4" perhaps?) threaded cap soldered on.
Standard "sprinkler-to-drip" adapters (which have a pressure regulator and some number of drip line connectors, possibly with a valve for each drip connection) are made for 1/2" threaded pipe. So you either need a threaded adapter from whatever the small threaded size (female) is up to 1/2 (male) pipe threads, or you'd remove the present reducing threaded fitting and install 1/2 male pipe threads via a Push To Connect or soldered fitting as your soldering skills and/or budget permit (PTC is easy but comparatively expensive - if you can solder pipe.)
The drip converter just screws on to the 1/2" male pipe threads, once you have those.

So I tried this, I used a 1/4" to 1/2" adapter, but the 1/4" was too large to screw in.  then I tried a 1/8" to 1/2", still too large. I'm going to take the top part that screws out to the hardware store, for exact comparison, but it's weird because when I measure the hole I need to get the adapter for, it's 1/4" big! (I'll update my OP).

Threaded pipe is sized by the hole in the pipe. Your best bet to match it would be taking the (unscrewed) sprinkler to the store and finding threads to match, but it seems like really it might be time to cut (or unsolder/resolder) and go from copper tubing to pipe threads directly if the threads there are a weird size.
